# SagePay Reporting API / getTransactionDetail / txstateid values

Tags: opayo

Is there a list of what the `txstateid` values mean when using the `getTransactionDetail` API?

Answer (score 0):

You will find the corresponding transaction status in the status field of the getTransactionDetail response. To help you fill in the blanks:

1              Transaction failed registration.  Either an INVALID or MALFORMED response was returned.

2              User on Card Selection page.

3              User on the Card Details Entry Page.

4              User on Confirmation Page.

5              Transaction at 3D-Secure Authentication Stage.

6              Transaction sent for Authorisation

7              Vendor Notified of transaction state at their NotificationURL.  Awaiting response.

8              Transaction CANCELLED by Sage Pay after 15 minutes of inactivity.  This is normally because the customer closed their browser.

9              Transaction completed but Vendor systems returned INVALID or ERROR in response to notification POST. Transaction CANCELLED by the Vendor.

10           Transaction REJECTED by the Fraud Rules you have in place.

11           Transaction ABORTED by the Customer on the Payment Pages.

12           Transaction DECLINED by the bank (NOTAUTHED).

13           An ERROR occurred at Sage Pay which cancelled this transaction.

14           Successful DEFERRED transaction, awaiting RELEASE.

15           Successful AUTHENTICATED transaction, awaiting AUTHORISE.

16           Successfully authorised transaction.

17           Transaction Timed Out at Authorisation Stage.

18           Transaction VOIDed by the Vendor.

19           Successful DEFERRED transaction ABORTED by the Vendor.

20           Transaction has been timed out by Sage Pay.

21           Successfully REGISTERED transaction, awaiting AUTHORISE.

22           AUTHENTICATED or REGISTERED transaction CANCELLED by the Vendor.

23           Transaction could not be settled with the bank and has been failed by the Sage Pay systems

24           PayPal Transaction Registered

25           Token Registered

26           AUTHENTICATE transaction that can no longer be AUTHORISED 
against.  It has either expired, or been fully authorised.

27           DEFERRED transaction that expired before it was RELEASEd or ABORTed.

28           Transaction waiting for authorisation.

29           Successfully authorised transaction.

30           The transaction failed.

31           The transaction failed due to invalid or incomplete data.

32           The transaction was aborted by the customer.

33           Transaction timed out at authorisation stage.

34           A remote ERROR occurred at Sage Pay which cancelled this transaction.

35           A local ERROR occurred at Sage Pay which cancelled this transaction.

36           The transaction could not be sent to the bank and has been failed by the Sage Pay systems.

37           The transaction was declined by the bank.

38           User at bank details page

39           User at Token Details page

I don't think you will ever see all of these (mostly 16s, hopefully), so I wouldn't try and test every outcome (you will be forever, and some of these statuses are caused by downstream failures, or issuer, acquirer etc).